# Convert array of objects with nested array of objects into array-like object

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object

Sorry about the title. I don't even know how I can explain what I want.

So here is what I am trying to achieve

```
const array = [
  {
    key: 0,
    key2: [ { id: "a", data: "abc" }, { id: "b", data: "wxy" }... ]
  },
  {
    key: 1,
    key2: [ { id: "a", data: "qwe" }, { id: "b", data: "zxc" }... ]
  },
...
]
```

I want to convert it to,

```
const result = {
    0 : {
        a: "abc",
        b: "wxy"
    },
    1 : {
        a: "qwe",
        b: "zxc"
    }
}
```

so far, I have this:

```
  const transforms = array
    .map((o) => {
      return { [o.key]: o.key2 };
    })
    .reduce((prev, curr) => {
      for (let key in curr)
        prev[key] = curr[key]
          .map((c) => {
            return { [c.id]: c.data};
          })
          .reduce((prev, curr) => {
            for (let key in curr) prev[key] = curr[key];
            return prev;
          }, {});

      return prev;
    }, {});
```

Which is hard to read, and probably not very performant.
To be honest, I don't even know if it is really 100% working.
It gave me expected result so far.

How do I refactor this?
Please help.

Comment: Probably a better question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Though please make sure you read [their help](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first

Comment: Didn't know that one, I will try there!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your task may be effectively decomposed into 4 tiny problems:

- Make key/value pair out of each `id`/`data` combination, which can be done using [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

```
key2.map(({id,data}) => ({[id]:data}))
```

- Combine those key/value pairs into a single object, using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
Object.assign({}, ...key2.map(({id,data}) => ({[id]:data})))
```

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your source array items into new array holding transformed `key2`

```
src.map(({key2}) => 
        Object.assign({}, ...key2.map(({id,data}) => ({[id]:data}))))
```

- [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) resulting array (which is essentially, an object) into the object

```
{...result} = src.map(({key2}) => 
        Object.assign({}, ...key2.map(({id,data}) => ({[id]:data}))))
```

Resulting code is way more compact and [works noticeably faster](https://jsbench.me/bukcbobixv/1)

You may find the live-demo as follows:

```js
const src = [{key:0,key2:[{id:"a",data:"abc"},{id:"b",data:"wxy"}]},{key:1,key2:[{id:"a",data:"qwe"},{id:"b",data:"zxc"}]}],

      {...result} = src.map(({key2}) => 
        Object.assign({}, ...key2.map(({id,data}) => ({[id]:data}))))
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [
    {
      key: 0,
      key2: [ { id: "a", data: "abc" }, { id: "b", data: "wxy" }]
    },
    {
      key: 1,
      key2: [ { id: "a", data: "qwe" }, { id: "b", data: "zxc" }]
    },

]

const result = array.reduce((res, entry) => {
    return Object.assign(res, { [entry.key]: entry.key2.reduce((data, current) => {
        return Object.assign(data, { [current.id]: current.data }) 
    }, {}) });
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Conversion function

```
array.reduce((res, entry) => {
    return Object.assign(res, { [entry.key]: entry.key2.reduce((data, current) => {
        return Object.assign(data, { [current.id]: current.data }) 
    }, {}) });
}, {})
```

Comment: See [my comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62770784/i-need-to-convert-array-of-objects-that-has-array-in-the-object-into-one-object/62770963?noredirect=1#comment111003824_62770963) on the above answer

Comment: You could've made your code a bit more compact by getting rid of unnecessary `return`'s and curly braces. Also, considering OP's concern about performance, your solution [does not provide that much of a gain](https://jsbench.me/bukcbobixv/1).